# Where is a python real project to be used as example for the unit-test part?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm looking for a python project to use as example to copy the design of the unit test parts.

The project should have these features:

1. its code is almost fully unit tested
2. the code is distributed in many packages, there are more that one level of packages
3. all the test can be run with a single command, for example with `python test.py`

I need that the project should use the same test convention for all the code contained. I saw the whole python project but the the various packages are tested with different conventions. For example the setuptools packages uses an ad hoc adaption of unittest library while the other packages doesn't.

I need that the project doesn't use a ad-hoc or a highly customized testing framework, because I want reuse its test architecture in my project.

Comment: @Andrea Fancia: Not "ad hoc".  It uses some unittest features instead of accepting the defaults blindly.

Comment: Not an EXACT duplicate -- but this has a slightly different focus.  In this case, "dear lazy web, I can't actually read all 15 standard packages to determine which meets my criteria."

Comment: Okay, it is more focused than the previous question.  I'll let the voting decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [Nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/) itself?

Answer (score 4):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is a clean project that has a nice range of unit testing.

[Have a look](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#topics-testing) at how they propose you test your own projects.

[Have a look](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/tests) at the unit testing code of the framework itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your specs point directly at a somewhat famous open source project, the [Python Library](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/). Have a look at [python/trunk/Lib/test/regrtest.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/regrtest.py?rev=63042&view=markup), which will find all modules whose name is "test_*" in the [test directory](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/), and run them.

Answer (score 0):

First, read about [unittest](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-unittest.html).  The documentation contains examples.

Second, since you want packages (not modules) the list is shorter.  There are 15 packages in Python 2.5 distribution.  Pick One At Random.  Here's a subset that might meet some of your criteria.

- bsddb: 7 modules - many test - test_all.py
- ctypes: 4 modules - tests - runtests.py
- distutils: many modules - tests - test_dist.py
- email: many modules - tests - test_email.py
- sqlite3 - 2 modules - tests - (not clear if there's an overall test, I got bored of looking)

Comment: the unittest module barely describe the asserts. it do not touch on the code/path organization. It never imports anything. It only touchs the filename subject to tell you how to make tests discoverable. and even then still won't tell you everything, e.g. do not mention what you should add as tests/testcase/etc on easysetup.

Answer (score 0):

You can check python's source. Most of it is written in python. specially the unittest modules.

<rant>python module organization and unittest in particular is a black art. It reminds me of a mix of perl (odd, undocumented workarounds for every basic thing --the unittest manual never even show how to import an external module) and java (restrictive directory and naming conventions)</rant>

take a look at the unit test setup for the [unittest module](https://hg.python.org/unittest2). (there is no source browse, you have to `hg clone` that url)

here is the setup.py portion to kick unittests, besides all the rest there:

```
# above here, juggle paths
from setuptools import setup
params['entry_points'] = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'unit2 = unittest2.__main__:main_',
    ],
}

params['test_suite'] = 'unittest2.collector'

setup(**params)
```

and even all they did is still not enough to simply run `setup.py test`. You will learn that most teams already gave up having what you are asking for and simply add a test_run.py or such to the project. I know all the project i contribute to did.

Take also a look at the nose answer above, that is a good one, their setup.py is very clean despite some 2, 3, 2to3 support craze. that is a project that aims to make unittest (and general testing) easier and more convenient. well, even them have a `selftest.py` script in the project root to try to kick the tests.